# DataTables child row IE and Edge confusing errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, cross-browser

I've been very confused by the errors I'm getting only on IE and Edge browsers for the [DataTables jquery plugin](https://datatables.net/). I've implemented [child rows](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html) on two tables that share the child rows code and it works as expected on Chrome and Firefox browsers. The code that opens/closes child rows is shared between the two tables.

The issue is that only one of the tables consistently gets an error when I try to show child rows. The error on Edge is `SCRIPT5022: IndexSizeError` and on IE it's `SCRIPT87: Invalid argument`. Either way, they both fail when the `row().child.show()` method runs. Even more specifically, it fails at the highlighted code below in the [v1.10.20 jquery.dataTables.js file](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.js):

[image]

As I mentioned, the other table that runs the same code does not fail and works perfectly, which makes this even more confusing. I'm not even sure what those errors mean or how to find exactly where it's failing.

I am currently in the process of trying to replicate it here: http://live.datatables.net/fuwuzibe/1/

The line `row.child(returnChildRowData(), 'classForChildRow');` is where the error would occur, but so far I cannot replicate it on Edge or IE.

If anyone has had an error like this before, I'd appreciate any input.

Comment: I'd suggest a JSFiddle, but IE11 falls over with JSFiddle doesn't it? Perhaps CodePen to illustrate your issue - interesting though and not something I've ever come across.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added a test case, but it's not very useful yet as I can't get the error to show up there on Edge or IE. It's really boggling my mind why it would work on Chrome and Firefox but not IE and Edge...